# can't run file extension aspx even it start server

Tags: asp.net

here is my code in my aspx file when i run it. it's show all code in the browser. i think it's maybe i don't import namespace but when i import it's still the same.

```
<% page language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ".......">
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.sqlClient" %>
<script language="vb" runat="server">
Private con As SqlConnection
Private command As SqlCommand
Private reader As SqlDataReader

sub Page_Load
        con = New SqlConnection("data source=ASUS-PC; database=personal; user id=sa; password=xxxxx;")
        con.Open()
end sub


</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
<% page language="VB" %>
```

To

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
```

Also, put your script tag inside the `<head>` tag, preferable with the `runat="server"` property. I strongly recommend you use the CodeBehind feature as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Server Manager > Roles > Web Server > Role Services and see if ASP.NET is installed.  By default, IIS only serves static content.